# Transacción Firebird en PHP

Tags: php, firebird

Buenos días,

Quiero hacer varias consultas a una base de datos Firebird usando una transacción, para que se haga un commit en caso de que todas las consultas se realicen con éxito o un rollback en caso de algún error en alguna consulta.

Lo que tengo en resumen es esto:

```
$tr = ibase_trans ($conexion, IBASE_DEFAULT);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO....";
$ejecuta1 = ibase_query ($tr, $sql1);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO...";
$ejecuta2 = ibase_query ($tr, $sql2);

ibase_commit($tr);
```

Para probarlo, introduzco un valor erróneo para un campo en la segunda consulta `$sql2`, pero lo que hace es ejecutar la primera consulta y tirar el error de la segunda, no hace caso a la transacción.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?.

Gracias de antemano! Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas revisar el resultado de cada Query para saber si manda error o no. No es necesario hacer una variable para cada `STRING` que son los querys y tampoco es necesario meter cada `QUERY` en una variable.

Considera lo siguiente; revisa cada transacción con operaciones ternarias y en caso de falla ejecuta rollback y termina el script PHP.

```
function errorEnTransaccion(&$link){
   ibase_rollback($link);
   exit('Error fatal, se hizo Rollback!');
}

$tr = ibase_trans ($conexion, IBASE_DEFAULT);

ibase_query ($tr, "INSERT INTO....") ? : errorEnTransaccion($tr);
ibase_query ($tr, "INSERT INTO...") ? : errorEnTransaccion($tr);

ibase_commit($tr);
```

¡NUNCA OLVIDES SANITIZAR TUS INPUTS!